# Узнать версию Runtime для сборки не загружая ее

Tags: c#

Мне нужно отобразить список всех сборок в `GAC`, а так же их `RuntimeVersion`.
Если делать так:

```
Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(systemAssemblyModel.Path).ImageRuntimeVersion;
```

то пямять забивается на лишние 80 мб и непонятно как их очистить. 
Если же загружать сборки полностью и затем выгружать ее вместе с доменом. То проиcходит `OutOfMemoryException`:

```
internal class Program
{    
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       var appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("TestDomain");    
       appDomain.DoCallBack(() => LoadModule());    
       var worker = (Worker) appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof (Worker).Assembly.FullName, typeof (Worker).FullName);
       var a1 = worker.GetAssembliesFullName();

       foreach (var assemblyFullName1 in a1)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(assemblyFullName1);
       }
       Console.WriteLine();
       var a2 = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
       foreach (var assembly1 in a2)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(assembly1.FullName);
       }
            AppDomain.Unload(appDomain);

       Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void LoadModule()
    {   
        foreach (var systemAssemblyModel in AssemblyLoader.LoadAssemblies())
        {
            try
            {
               var version = Assembly.Load(systemAssemblyModel.Desc.Path).ImageRuntimeVersion;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }
     }    
}

class Worker : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public string[] GetAssembliesFullName()
    {
         return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Select(a => a.FullName).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Вам поможет пакет [`Mono.Cecil`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.Cecil/)

Comment: 80 мегабайт — не так уж и много. Может, скомбинировать? Грузить только для рефлексии и в новом домене?

Comment: Проблема в том что при повторном открытии формы эти 80 мегабайт снова загрузятся. Грузить только для рефлексии в новом домене не получится. При выгрузке домена, память остается заполненной

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Может кому пригодится. По совету

> Вам поможет пакет [Mono.Cecil](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.Cecil/) – Pavel Mayorov

Подключил библиотеку и использовал следующий код

```
AssemblyDefinition assembly = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(assemblyDescription.Path);
Console.WriteLine(assemblyDescription.Name + " " + assembly.MainModule.RuntimeVersion);
```

Comment: Не забудьте отметить свой ответ зеленой галочкой через 3 дня.

Answer (score 2):

У меня работает так без использования доп. библиотек, но получает только лишь версию вида 1.0.5.124:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Без выполнения загрузки файла в память (актуально для сборок) возвращает версию файла Filename в переменную 
    /// типа Version если файл существует и возможно получение номера версии.
    /// Если файл не существует — возвращает null.
    /// Если номер версии не удается получить для файла, то все поля результата будут нулевыми (0.0.0.0).
    /// Если имя файла не указано, то возвращает сведения для выполняемой сборки.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Filename">путь к файлу для вычисления версии.</param>
    /// <remarks>Правильнее и надежнее использовать метод GetFileVersionInfo.</remarks>
    public static Version GetFileVersion(string Filename = "")
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Filename)) { Filename = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location; }
        if (!File.Exists(Filename)) { return null; }
        Version version = new Version();
        try
        {
            FileVersionInfo vi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Filename);
            version = new Version(vi.ProductVersion);
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {
            //Не можем определить версию файла, и, перемнную для обработки ошибки не ловим, т.к. 
            //её не обрабатываем, а делаем вид, что у файла нулевая версия.
            version = new Version(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        return version;
    }
```

А вот простенький метод, возвращающий больше информации:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Возвращает сведения о версии и параметрах файла в переменную класса FileVersionInfo без загрузки файла 
    /// в память (не блокирует файл).
    /// Если файл не существует, то возвращает null.
    /// Если имя файла не указано, то возвращает сведения для выполняемой сборки.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Filename">Имя файла для получения сведений о версии.</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Если получить версию файла невозможно (например, для файлов, отличных от EXE и DLL), то возвращает 
    /// практически пустую структуру класса FileVersionInfo БЕЗ генерации ошибки.
    /// </remarks>
    public static FileVersionInfo GetFileVersionInfo(string Filename = "")
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Filename)) { Filename = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location; }
        if (!File.Exists(Filename)) { return null; }
        return FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Filename);
    }
```

Comment: это версия файла для GAC сборок ее еще можно получить из пути файла использовав, что-то вроде path.Split(',')[1]; А вот версия runtime это версия фреймворка, на котором работает сборка